# Android studio - FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, fatal-error

I am trying to switch between 2 activities in android studio, the problem is whenever I press the button the program crash and stop working, here is the error :

```
>  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.talal.furnitureorder, PID: 19310
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.talal.furnitureorder/com.example.talal.furnitureorder.Invoice}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Number of Chairs:"
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Number of Chairs:"
                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                      at com.example.talal.furnitureorder.Invoice.onCreate(Invoice.java:48)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

my XML code for activity 1:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.talal.furnitureorder.Order">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Customer Name"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/e1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Customer Address"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/e2"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Customer City"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/e3"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Number of Chairs ordered"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/e4"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Number of Sofas ordered"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/e5"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Print the Invoice"
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:onClick="print"
            android:layout_marginTop="10pt" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:onClick="reset"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my Java code for activity 1:

```
    package com.example.talal.furnitureorder;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Order extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4,ed5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

    }

    public void print (View view){

        Intent t=new Intent (this,Invoice.class);
        ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
        ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.e2);
        ed3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.e3);
        ed4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.e4);
        ed5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.e5);

        Bundle b=new Bundle();

        b.putString("name",ed1.getText().toString());
        b.putString("address",ed2.getText().toString());
        b.putString("city",ed3.getText().toString());
        b.putString("C_NO",ed4.getText().toString());
        b.putString("S_NO",ed5.getText().toString());




        t.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(t);

    }

    }
```

my XML code for activity2 :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.talal.furnitureorder.Invoice">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv6"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv7"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv8"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New"
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my java code for activity2:

```
    package com.example.talal.furnitureorder;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Invoice extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8;
    int c, s;
    int p, tp;
    int tx;


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invoice);




        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv6);
        t7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv7);
        t8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv8);

        Bundle bb = getIntent().getExtras();

        String s1 = bb.getString("name");
        String s2 = bb.getString("address");
        String s3 = bb.getString("city");
        String s4 = bb.getString("C_NO");
        String s5 = bb.getString("S_NO");

        t1.setText("Customer Name:" + s1);
        t2.setText("Customer Address:" + s2);
        t3.setText("Customer City:" + s3);
        t4.setText("Number of Chairs:" + s4);
        t5.setText("Number of Sofas:" + s5);

        c = Integer.parseInt(t4.getText().toString());
        s = Integer.parseInt(t5.getText().toString());

        p = (350 * c) + (925 * s);

        t6.setText("Price is: $" + p);


    }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView t4` contains the text `Number of Chairs:` which is not an integer. So it throws `NumberFormatException`.

If you are trying to parse number of chairs retrieved from `Order` Activity, try changing your code from

```
c = Integer.parseInt(t4.getText().toString());
s = Integer.parseInt(t5.getText().toString());
```

to

```
c = Integer.parseInt(s4);
s = Integer.parseInt(s5);
```

And since your are trying to parse data retrieved from `EditText`, I would suggest you use `try catch block` i.e

```
try{
  c = Integer.parseInt(s4);
  s = Integer.parseInt(s5);
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
   ...
}
```

UPDATE

To send 0 in case `EditText` is empty

Order.java

```
 String c_no = ed4.getText().toString();
 String s_np = ed5.getText().toString();
 b.putString("C_NO",TextUtils.isEmpty(c_no)? 0 : c_no);
 b.putString("S_NO",TextUtils.isEmpty(s_np)? 0 : s_np);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm...I have been searching and searching ..you are my savor :D

Comment: hmm it worked first and everything was fine, but then I tried to close application and reopen the simulation it show the same error again..any suggestions ?

Comment: That's because studio 2.0 and up has instant run which includes code patches. When you exit the app it discontinues the run process. and it doesn't have actual changes you made in your installed app. Rebuild and reinstall project. You will see it keeps working even after reopening the app.

Comment: I am using 1.5.1 version - and I rechecked my code still the same ...
I did rebuild my project and reinstall it .. but still the same error which is completely weird

Comment: oh nevermind.. the problem was if I didn't write any number in charis and sofas in first activity it force close, but when I write numbers the program works fine ...is there anyway to put 0 by default if I didn't write any number ?

Comment: @FabinPaul I tried to add the updated code, but it shows the following problem "wrong 2nd argument type. found:java.io.serializable required java.lang.string

Comment: @FabinPaul oh I fixed it by adding string quotation to 0 > "0" 
thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are doing this, but the problem is in `Activity2` right here:

```
    t4.setText("Number of Chairs:" + s4);
    t5.setText("Number of Sofas:" + s5);

    c = Integer.parseInt(t4.getText().toString());
    s = Integer.parseInt(t5.getText().toString());
```

You are setting `t4` to a `String` with the value "Number of Chairs:" and then trying to pull that same value out and `parse` it to an `Integer` - that's not gonna happen.

Not sure what you are trying to do, but it's likely you will need 2 Fields - one to hold the `String` and one to hold the `Integer`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
 c = Integer.parseInt(t4.getText().toString());
```

You cannot parse string "Number of chairs: 4" f.e and get integer. Try instead:

```
 c = Integer.parseInt(s4);
```

That is provided your EditText input only allowed numbers. Same for sofas btw.

Edit: I can see as I was typing the answer was provided above for you.

Comment: I tried to do what you wrote me, it worked first .. but I closed the simulation and reopen it and it gave me back the same error..any suggestions ?

Comment: If you're using studio 2.0 and up it's probably because it didn't save the instant run code edits once you closed the app.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     c = Integer.parseInt(t4.getText().toString());
> ```

The content of your textview is more than just a number, this way you can't parse it to an integer, therefore it crashes.